# Using a list in java

Tags: java, list

So I had a question, which I won't go into too much detail because I managed to correctly code it into an array. Or at least, code it into an array that worked correctly; as follows:

```
static double getSolution (int n)
{
   double [] w = new double [n];
   w[0] = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       w[i + 1] = w[i] + (( 2 / 3*n ) * Math.cos (w[i]) );           
    }
    double x = w[n];
    return x;
}
```

I then found out I was not meant to have coded it using an array, but instead using a list. I have attempted this, and the following is the code I have come up with:

```
static double getSolution1 (int n)
{
    List <double> w = new ArrayList <double>();
    w[0] = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        w[i+1] = w[i] + ((2 / 3*n ) * Math.cos (w[i]) );
    }
    return w[n];
}
```

Now I know this is wrong from the start off, but could anybody tell me what I have done wrong and where? Also; when attempted to compile I get the error message "cannot find symbol - class List".

EDIT 1: I have tried changing the line to Double instead of double has many people have suggested, I am still getting the exact same compiling error.

EDIT 2: So if I was to transcribe the array into a list, what would the correct code be? Because I'm really confused as to how I'm supposed to write it out.

Comment: "cannot find symbol - class List" <-- You are *missing* an import for [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (i.e. `java.util.*`) and not using a FQN (Fully Qualified Name).

Comment: @user2864740 check out my ans

Comment: @user2864740 eww `java.util.*`. Star imports are disgusting (I feel). Rather, use an IDE that will automatically import for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
List <Double> w = new ArrayList <Double>();
```

instead of

```
List <double> w = new ArrayList <double>();
```

double is a primitive type but list will accept only object so thats use `Double`. `Double` is a wrapper over primitive type double.

Edit:

```
w[0] this is not list operation so if you are using this type of operation to access element you should use array. else mperform add remove operations
```

Check List operations: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html`

you must declare import statement for packages

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

so Your method become 
**Using array**

```
static double getSolution1 (int n)
{
    Double[] w = new Double[n+1];
    w[0] = -1d;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        w[i+1] = w[i] + ((2 / 3*n ) * Math.cos (w[i]) );
    }
    return w[n];
}
```

**Using List**

```
static double getSolution1(int n) {
    List<Double> w = new ArrayList<Double>();
    w.add(-1d);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double d = w.get(i) + ((2 / 3 * n) * Math.cos(w.get(i)));
        w.add(d);
    }
    return w.get(n);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am still getting the error "cannoy find symbol - class List".

Comment: @user3013480 My answer is the only one (at this moment) that solves that

Comment: Also, why do you have final int n instead of just int n?

Comment: Ugh, you totally ripped off my answer; I was the only one who noticed the import part.

Comment: @user3013480 final is a keyword not related with your problem. so removed.

Comment: @user3013480 you must import java util package and if you still get the same error. Please paste your full class in your question

Answer (score 1):

Generics are meant to be used for classes, not for primitive types.

Just change the code to use [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) instead of `double`:

```
List <Double> w = new ArrayList <Double>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoule have

```
List <Double> w = new ArrayList <Double>();
```

instead of

```
List <double> w = new ArrayList <double>();
```

Because collection framework does not allow primitive data type, it only accepts Wrapper classes of the primitive data type.

Comment: Not collection framework only, but every class/interface using generics

Answer (score 0):

In java each primary data type has its Object type.
e.g.

```
int --> Integer
double --> Double
byte --> Byte
```

If you want to put your primary data into a collections, you need to declare the collection with the number's corresponding Object type.

So,

```
List <Double> w = new ArrayList <Double>();
```

will work.

And

```
double d = 12.34;
w.add(d);
```

will also work. Java will convert d into Double type automatically. The mechanism is called auto-boxing.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you have not imported the `List` interface and the `ArrayList` class. Insert this code at the beginning of the file:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Alternatively, you can do this (no imports needed):

```
static double getSolution1 (int n)
{
    //If you do the import, remove the java.util. that follows.
    //This also fixes the other errors.
    java.util.List <Double> w = new java.util.ArrayList<Double>();
    //w[0] = -1; //this does not work; a list is not an array.
    w.add(-1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //w[i+1] = w[i] + ((2 / 3*n ) * Math.cos (w[i]) ); this does not work either;
        //                                                 just add the result to the list.
        w.add(w.get(i) + ((2 / 3*n ) * Math.cos (w.get(i) );
    }
    return w.get(n);
}
```

Here is an explanation of the changes I made (other than `java.util.List` or the `import`s):

For the generic type, `double` does not work. You need to use a `Double` (the wrapper class for a `double`), thus the code changes from `List<double>` to `List<Double>`. This is necessary to Java because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At compile time, the generic type is removed and the `List` is treated as if it were a list of Objects. Since primitives are not Objects, we need the wrapper class.

Rather than using `w[0]=-1;`, we use `w.add(-1);`. `w` is an object, not an array, thus cannot be accessed with `[number]`. Luckily, `List` has some useful methods; namely `List#add()` and `List#get()`. Calling `w.add(-1)` appends `-1` to the end of the list.

For the `w[i+1]` part in the loop, we simply add the new element, using `w.get(i)` rather than `w[i]`.

Comment: w[0] this type of operation is not performed on list

Comment: @AshishAggarwal I know; I specifically said I did not fix the errors. I have fixed them now. Also, note that my answer was the only one that noticed the actual problem the OP stated. You really need to pay attention to answers, and it is helpful to note downvote until the writer has a chance to edit.

Comment: Nowhere in my notes from my course does it say either the import or the java.util.list; is there perhaps another way to do it where I specify it as a class or something?

Comment: @user3013480 The only other way without import or the `java.util.List` is to create your own list or copy the code and compile it yourself. Do not do either of those. Either import or use the `java.util.List` or (best) continue with you array.

Comment: I thought there was a way to do it where I define List as a class but I'm not 100% sure how to d that? If in fact I'm right in thinking that

Comment: @user3013480 Can you clarify what you are saying? Also, if you like my answer, remember to upvote.

Comment: Ah, I see what I was misreading in my lecturers notes. I completely missed the import at the top of coding, as he did it outside of the entire code, not just by the List example. Thank you!

Comment: @user3013480 If you liked the answer, and it answered your question, you can accept it.

Comment: Well your answer and another answer both answered two different parts of the question.

Comment: @user3013480 Which answer solved your problem (the one you were asking about) the most? Accept that one (note that this answer now has more material)

Answer (score 0):

You should only use a List where the data is not always a fixed size. They add extra overhead compared to a regular array.

To create a List object, use an implementation like ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Double> w = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

You also don't access a list via [].

```
w.get(index) // Gets value. Throws exception if index is greater than or equal to size() or less than 0.
w.add(index, value);  // Adds value
w.set(index, value);  // Replaces value
```